# C# Add validation list to excel error

Tags: c#, excel, validation

I'm writing a program to add a set of user data to the excel file.
Some of the cells need to have a drop down list, which is a validation list. The list of data is provided by user.

While exporting the data to excel using C# code, sometimes the data will cause programs but sometimes not.

There's no error from program side when I add data

```
validationValues.Add("Interface Phase 1 Cycle3");
validationValues.Add("Performance Testing");
validationValues.Add("Pre SIT (HLB)");
validationValues.Add("Pre-SIT FE (EtoE) Phase1 C1");
validationValues.Add("Sanity Test(HLB)");
validationValues.Add("SIT Cycle 1 (HLB)");
validationValues.Add("SIT Cycle 2 (HLB)");
validationValues.Add("SIT Cycle 3 (HLB)");
validationValues.Add("SIT FE (EtoE) Phase1 C1");
validationValues.Add("SIT FE (EtoE) Phase1 C2");
validationValues.Add("SIT FE (EtoE) Phase1 C3");
validationValues.Add("SIT Sanity Check");
validationValues.Add("SIT STB Cycle 1");
validationValues.Add("SIT STB Cycle 2");
validationValues.Add("SIT STB Cycle 3");
validationValues.Add("SIT STB Sanity Check");
validationValues.Add("SIT STB User Interface Issues");
validationValues.Add("SIT WOG Phase1 C1");
validationValues.Add("SIT WOG Phase1 C2");
validationValues.Add("SIT WOG Phase1 C3");
if (validationValues.Count != 0)
    AddDataValidation(xlWorkSheet, validationValues, "R:R");
validationValues.Clear();
```

In AddDataValidation function:

```
    private static void AddDataValidation(Excel.Worksheet worksheet, List<string> validationValues, string col)
    {
        try
        {

            string values = string.Join(",", validationValues);
            Excel.Range column = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns[col, Type.Missing];
            column.Validation.Delete();
            column.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, values, Type.Missing);
            column.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true; 

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //This part should not be reached, but is used for stability-reasons
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Error when adding a Validation with restriction to the specified Column:{0}, Message: {1}", col, exception));

        }
    }
```

The error is like this:
[image: Error 1 when open excel]
[image: Error 2 when accept excel correction]
**Upon opening of the excel file, it removes the validation feature, no drop down list will shown to the cells.**

The XML file contents are here:

error025200_02.xmlErrors were detected in file 'C:\Users\wendylinlin\Desktop\Reports-Common20152241477_Defects.xlsx'Removed Feature: Data validation from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

However, if I comment out the validations values with bracket, means don't add in those with ( or ), the validation is working fine and I can see the drop down list after open excel.

**I tried to do a string manipulation, replace all "(" and ")" with a space, but it gives the same error. Some other strings with "-" and "," give the similar problem as well. But replacement of the special characters don't help at all for all cases.**

Anyone have idea what's happening? How can I have the correct validation value to the excel and prevent excel to remove the validation list?

Thank you!!

Comment: **I just checked and found the problem is caused by the length of strings in the AddDataValidation function. If the values is more than 255, excel is not able to open the file correctly. Anyone has Idea why is it so? An excel sheet should be able to contain MAX 32767 chars instead of 255 chars.**

Comment: I checked on some forum discussion, it is found the Validation.Add function only accept a list with maximum 255 characters. If you desire a list with more characters and items inside, the only way is to store the list in the excel sheet, and give a specific range for the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I checked on some forum discussion, it is found the Validation.Add function only accept a list with maximum 255 characters. If you desire a list with more characters and items inside, the only way is to store the list in the excel sheet, and give a specific range for the list.** To hide the value from user, actually I use a unused excel column and hide the column for the drop down list values.
This is the only alternative way I found to work with this problem.

```
for (int valueNum = 0; valueNum < bug.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.CrimsonLogic.TargetVersion"].AllowedValues.Count; valueNum++)
{
    //use unused columns to add validation value
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[valueNum + 1, 27] = bug.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.CrimsonLogic.TargetVersion"].AllowedValues[valueNum].ToString();
}
//Column R is where I want the drop down list to be
ValidationValueCol = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns["R:R", Type.Missing];
ValidationValueCol.Validation.Delete();
strconfig = "='" + Sheetname+ "'!$AA$1:$AA$" + (bug.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.CrimsonLogic.TargetVersion"].AllowedValues.Count+1);
//Add the validation range with the pre-stored list
ValidationValueCol.Validation.Add(XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, strconfig, Type.Missing);
ValidationValueCol.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
HideColumn(xlWorkSheet, "AA");
```